# How to insert date type with slashes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I receive below error message when I tried to insert date in a table:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
create table test (
  [date] date
) 
go

insert into test
  values ('17/12/2015')
```

Comment: Have a look at [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Answer (score 1):

Try use other formats to insert like:

('12/17/2015')

('2015-12-17')

...

If need more supported formats of date type, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store date in this format directly. First First need to convert it into certain regional format.

```
create table test (
  [date] date
) 
go

insert into test
  values ( CAST('11/10/2011' AS DATETIME))
```

You may check this link for more info about DateTime conversion in SQL [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).

Comment: have you try this query with date more than 12?  ie. '17/12/2015'

Answer (score 0):

Hi You just need to set `Dateformat` in `Insert` Query

```
set dateformat DMY 
INSERT INTO test 
   VALUES ('17/12/2015');
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d6af2d516c28a9d1aba2384dbb251e0)**